# Eclipse format array the way I want

Tags: java, eclipse

Currently the formatter option in latest eclipse does not formatting the way I want.

This is example how it format an array

```
private final int[][] ARRAY =
    {
        {
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        },
        {
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        },
    };
```

But this is the way I want.

```
private final int[][] ARRAY =
{
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
};
```

I tried all settings but nothing make it that way. Is there any plugin with extra formatting options or any way I can write my own option inside formatter to make the array that way?

Comment: You can edit all the eclipse formatter settings yourself. >> Project -> Properties -> Java Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit. And then what you search for is probably under the Tab "Braces".

Comment: You didn't even read what i wrote.

Comment: Well, "I tried all settings but nothing make it that way" isn't too discriptive. So I assumed I would guide you to the settings that I guessed would help you. I'm pretty sure that "your way you want it" isn't quite possible with a rule-based formatter. Because you want to handle the same kind of braces (Array Initializer braces) differently.

Comment: Is there any way to create my own formater setting via XML code or something?

Comment: Regarding your first comment, please read the [Code of Conduct - Unacceptable Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct#unacceptable-behavior). Regarding your second comment, yes, you can implemented your own formatter in Java as documented. XML will not work for the reasons already mentioned by maloomeister.